# CSS - Strange border appearing on Chrome mobile with clip-path

Tags: css, google-chrome

I used basic CSS `clip-path` to create a "slope" as seen below. Problem is, using a Chrome browser on mobile creates a "border" that is not defined anywhere in my CSS. What's stranger, on desktop Chrome and on Firefox (desktop/mobile) it doesn't appear. I double checked all HTML elements and none of them has a borders. I'm also using Bootstrap 3. Here's what I'm talking about:

**Chrome Mobile**

[image: Chrome]

**Firefox**

[image: Firefox]

Not sure if needed but this is the `clip-path` code:

```
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 58% 0%, 64% 100%, 0% 100%);
```

Is it a known Chrome bug? Has someone else encoutered this problem?

**Edit**

Full HTML. The clip-path is applied to `#footer`

```
<section id="sub-footer">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="footer" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="column ">
                <div class="module ">
                    <div class="module-content">
                        <div class="custom">
                            <div class="container"><a href=""></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Paste code here if you can.

Comment: @LokeshGupta Added HTML

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542919/clip-path-on-chrome-leaves-a-strange-line-on-the-edge seems related and has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying `transform: scaleZ(1)` to the element with `clip-path`. No idea why this is happening in Chrome, even 7 whole years later, nor why this hack fixes it. Thanks goes to this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542919/clip-path-on-chrome-leaves-a-strange-line-on-the-edge).