# Clip-path on Chrome leaves a strange line on the edge

Tags: css, google-chrome, clip-path

I use **clip-path** to create the particular shape of the blue search button.

From Chrome you see a strange line at the cutout edge, while from Firefox everything is OK.

I am not the first to point this out, but I have not found a solution.

**Chrome**

[image]

**Firefox**

[image]

The clip-path is:

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
```

What mystery is this? I also found a similar issue:

[CSS - Strange border appearing on Chrome mobile with clip-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840094/css-strange-border-appearing-on-chrome-mobile-with-clip-path)

Comment: can you share your code ?

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar (if not the same) issue, I fixed this by adding the following style to the element with the `clip-path`:

```
 transform: translateZ(0)
```

Comment: or `transform:scaleZ(1)` which is shorter - for cssbattle lovers :)

Comment: Would you be able to provide an explanation on why this fixes the issue? It does work for me, but I'd like to understand why

Comment: I believe this works because it puts the element into a sort of "3d" rendering mode which does not seem to have the same issue.

Comment: this is still happening in 2024. any idea why this occurs and why this fixes it?

Answer (score 7):

In my case suggested `transform: translateZ(0)` and `transform: scaleZ(1)` did not help but this one yes...

```
transform: skewY(0.001deg);
```

UPDATE: it fixed problem on some devices but not on another devices with the same chrome version (!). So this Chromium bug is very unpleasant and unhackable easily. We must refactored it from the scratch and create triangles as part of whole arrow button using clip-path CSS property...

`clip-path: polygon(30px 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 30px 100%, 0 50%);`

Here is a tool to generate clip-paths: https://unused-css.com/tools/clip-path-generator

Comment: Thanks. In my case `transform: scaleZ(1.00001)` did the trick.

Comment: @xfra35 when I removed my solution and used your it is the same on some devices, but as I just edited answer, both my and your solution unfortunately does not work in all devices. We must use clip-path to create not just tringle but whole object and with this way there is not possibility for that 1px stripe browser bug.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue where the right edge of a clip path was sitting just inside of 100%. I was able to fix this by setting the right edge x-coordinate values to 101% and adding `overflow: hidden;` to the parent element.

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 101% 0, 101% 80%, 0 100%);
```

I imagine you could do the same on the left side by inputting negative values?

[Image before fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HzKz.jpg)

[Image after fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aikfR.jpg)

Comment: I've also discovered this. Negative values work. I like this method since it doesn't have any side effects.

Comment: I had to knock top left and top right into negative values on the Y-axis to get this to work.. and it worked