# Remove unknown line after creating clip-path

Tags: html, css

I am creating a footer and get this line [(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlGWP.png) that i want to remove This is the main elements of the code:

```css
footer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--black);
  padding: 0 20px 10px 20px;
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  p,
  a {
    color: var(--white);
    font-size: var(--small-font-size);
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  img {
    height: 70px;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  div,
  img {
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
}

.visual-triangle {
  background-color: var(--white);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 100%, 100% 0);
  border: none;
}

.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  a {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}

:root {
  --primary-color: #8245c2;
  --secondary-color: #bcbec0;
  --black: #000000;
  --white: #ffffff;
  /*base font size */
  font-size: 16px;
}


/* Reset and default styles for all elements */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: MontserratRegular;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  word-spacing: 0.03em;
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1150px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: MontserratBlack;
  font-size: 1.728rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

h2 {
  font-family: MontserratBlack;
  font-size: 1.44rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

h3 {
  font-family: MontserratBold;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<main id="mainContent">
  <div class="card-tjeneste">
    <h1>Lorem</h1>
    <div>
      <div class="icon-grid">
        <p>tekst</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-grid">
        <p>tekst</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-grid">
        <p>tekst</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-grid">
        <p>tekst</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-delesalg background">
    <h2>Lorem</h2>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h3>Lorem</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias, id!</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="assets/images/skål.png" alt="">
        <h3>Lorem</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, amet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="les-mer-container">
      <button class="les-mer"><a href="delesalg.html">button</a></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-hvem">
    <div>
      <h2>Lorem</h2>
      <img src="assets/images/meg.png" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat vitae voluptas minus veritatis velit repudiandae corrupti doloribus nulla placeat quis.</p>
      <div class="les-mer-container">
        <button class="les-mer"><a href="om-meg.html">button</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer aria-label="Site Footer">
    <div class="visual-triangle"></div>
    <!-- SCROLL TO TOP BUTTON -->
    <div class="scroll">
      <a href="#mainContent" aria-label="skip back to top">&#11205;</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="copyright" tabindex="0">Copyright &#169; </p>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

I tried adding a border none, as i thought that was the problem but nothing happend. After just trying to remove certain elements, such as h1 from the CSS it suddenly disappeared, but that did not make any sense.

I found similar posts, saying it is a chrome issue?(?), but nothing from previous posts has worked on my code, ex. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542919/clip-path-on-chrome-leaves-a-strange-line-on-the-edge)

Is there other ways to removed it, or any other way I can make the same effect?

EDIT:
I also tried this, but i get the same line

```css
.visual-triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50vw solid transparent; 
    border-right: 50vw solid transparent; 
    border-top: 30px solid var(--white); 
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

Comment: The line is part of `.visual-triangle` itself, so that is likely some sort of rounding issue when it comes to the application of the clip-path. If you pull the triangle up via `margin-top: -1px`, and add `overflow: hidden` on the `footer` element, you can "hide" it pretty easily though.

Comment: `footer {
    position: relative;
    background-color: var(--black);

    margin-top: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}`

like this right? it didnt do anything..

Comment: No, the negative margin-top on the triangle element itself (so that that gets "pulled out" of the footer at the top, and then the `overflow:hidden` will _hide_ that part, that is outside.)

Comment: Ah yes i have tried that too, but it dosen't work either

Comment: "reset" part way through the CSS cascade is a bit unusual.

Comment: Code format shows the HTML is malformed as posted more clearly.

Comment: I have it differently in my actual code, just because i removed several parts for privacy reasons

Comment: _"Ah yes i have tried that too, but it dosen't work either"_ - don't see the effect any more in Firefox or Chrome, with this https://jsfiddle.net/ky4Laqud/

Answer (score 0):

Don't add a triangle above the black part to hide part of it. Apply the `clip-path` to the black part instead.

Here is a simplified example:

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0;
  background: #000;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 30%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.box div {
  width: 50px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  margin: auto;
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>
```