How to match a curve with circle radius in CSS?
I have the following design created by a Youtube tutorial about magic indicators:

But I want a smooth, not so steep curve as a continuation of the circle when selected instead of using element with small border-radius like in the original solution and I don't know how to make it perfectly match the border of the circle. Code snippet is below. On the screenshot below I show with arrows the places where I make manual adjustments which don't completely work. I'm looking for a CSS-only solution.



const indicator = document.querySelector("[data-indicator]")

document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  let anchor
  if (e.target.matches("a")) {
    anchor = e.target
  } else {
    anchor = e.target.closest("a")
  }
  if (anchor != null) {
    const allAnchors = [...document.querySelectorAll("a")]
    const index = allAnchors.indexOf(anchor)
    indicator.style.setProperty("--position", index)
    document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(elem => {
      elem.classList.remove("active")
    })
    anchor.classList.add("active")
  }
})
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  color: white;
}

:root {
  --icon-size: 2rem;
  --indicator-spacing: calc(var(--icon-size) / 8);
  --border-radius: calc(var(--icon-size) / 4);
  --nav-item-padding: calc(var(--icon-size) / 2);
  --background-color: #333;
}

.navbar-container {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10rem;
  padding: 0 calc(var(--nav-item-padding) * 1.5);
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.list a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: var(--nav-item-padding);
}

.list .text {
  font-size: .8em;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 250ms ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(.5 * var(--nav-item-padding));
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

.list .icon {
  position: relative;
  transition: 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.list .icon svg {
  fill: currentColor;
  width: var(--icon-size);
  height: var(--icon-size);
  display: block;
}

.list .active .text {
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.list .active .icon {
  transform: translateY(calc(-50% - var(--nav-item-padding)));
}

/* .list .active::before {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--border-radius);
  height: var(--border-radius);
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--indicator-spacing));
  left: calc(.2 * var(--indicator-spacing));
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  border-width: calc(var(--indicator-spacing));
  border-color: var(--background-color);
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
}

.list .active::after {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--border-radius);
  height: var(--border-radius);
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--indicator-spacing));
  right: calc(.2 * var(--indicator-spacing));
  transform: translateX(100%);
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-width: calc(var(--indicator-spacing));
  border-color: var(--background-color);
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
} */

.list {
  position: relative;
}

.indicator {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(var(--position) * (var(--icon-size) + var(--nav-item-padding) * 2));
  transition: 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.indicator::after,
.indicator::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.indicator::after {
  background-color: hsl(100, 100%, 50%);
  width: calc(var(--icon-size) * 2);
  height: calc(var(--icon-size) * 2);
  top: calc(-1 * var(--icon-size));
}
.indicator::before {
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  width: calc((var(--icon-size) + var(--indicator-spacing)) * 2);
  height: calc((var(--icon-size) + var(--indicator-spacing)) * 2);
  top: calc(-1 * var(--icon-size) - var(--indicator-spacing));
  left: calc(-1 * var(--indicator-spacing));
}

.corners::before {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--border-radius);
  height: var(--border-radius);
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--indicator-spacing));
  left: calc(.2 * var(--indicator-spacing));
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  border-width: calc(var(--indicator-spacing));
  border-color: var(--background-color);
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
}

.corners::after {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--border-radius);
  height: var(--border-radius);
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--indicator-spacing));
  left: calc(var(--icon-size) * 2 + -.2 * var(--indicator-spacing));
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-width: calc(var(--indicator-spacing));
  border-color: var(--background-color);
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar-container">
    <ul class="list">
      <div style="--position: 0;" data-indicator class="indicator">
        <div class="corners"></div>
      </div>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">
        <div class="icon">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" ><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M12 5.69l5 4.5V18h-2v-6H9v6H7v-7.81l5-4.5M12 3L2 12h3v8h6v-6h2v6h6v-8h3L12 3z"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="text">Home</div>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">
        <div class="icon">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M12 5.9c1.16 0 2.1.94 2.1 2.1s-.94 2.1-2.1 2.1S9.9 9.16 9.9 8s.94-2.1 2.1-2.1m0 9c2.97 0 6.1 1.46 6.1 2.1v1.1H5.9V17c0-.64 3.13-2.1 6.1-2.1M12 4C9.79 4 8 5.79 8 8s1.79 4 4 4 4-1.79 4-4-1.79-4-4-4zm0 9c-2.67 0-8 1.34-8 4v3h16v-3c0-2.66-5.33-4-8-4z"/></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="text">Account</div>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">
        <div class="icon">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M20 2H4c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v18l4-4h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 14H6l-2 2V4h16v12z"/></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="text">Messages</div>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">
        <div class="icon">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M14.12 4l1.83 2H20v12H4V6h4.05l1.83-2h4.24M15 2H9L7.17 4H4c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h16c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V6c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2h-3.17L15 2zm-3 7c1.65 0 3 1.35 3 3s-1.35 3-3 3-3-1.35-3-3 1.35-3 3-3m0-2c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 5s2.24 5 5 5 5-2.24 5-5-2.24-5-5-5z"/></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="text">Photos</div>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">
        <div class="icon">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M19.43 12.98c.04-.32.07-.64.07-.98 0-.34-.03-.66-.07-.98l2.11-1.65c.19-.15.24-.42.12-.64l-2-3.46c-.09-.16-.26-.25-.44-.25-.06 0-.12.01-.17.03l-2.49 1c-.52-.4-1.08-.73-1.69-.98l-.38-2.65C14.46 2.18 14.25 2 14 2h-4c-.25 0-.46.18-.49.42l-.38 2.65c-.61.25-1.17.59-1.69.98l-2.49-1c-.06-.02-.12-.03-.18-.03-.17 0-.34.09-.43.25l-2 3.46c-.13.22-.07.49.12.64l2.11 1.65c-.04.32-.07.65-.07.98 0 .33.03.66.07.98l-2.11 1.65c-.19.15-.24.42-.12.64l2 3.46c.09.16.26.25.44.25.06 0 .12-.01.17-.03l2.49-1c.52.4 1.08.73 1.69.98l.38 2.65c.03.24.24.42.49.42h4c.25 0 .46-.18.49-.42l.38-2.65c.61-.25 1.17-.59 1.69-.98l2.49 1c.06.02.12.03.18.03.17 0 .34-.09.43-.25l2-3.46c.12-.22.07-.49-.12-.64l-2.11-1.65zm-1.98-1.71c.04.31.05.52.05.73 0 .21-.02.43-.05.73l-.14 1.13.89.7 1.08.84-.7 1.21-1.27-.51-1.04-.42-.9.68c-.43.32-.84.56-1.25.73l-1.06.43-.16 1.13-.2 1.35h-1.4l-.19-1.35-.16-1.13-1.06-.43c-.43-.18-.83-.41-1.23-.71l-.91-.7-1.06.43-1.27.51-.7-1.21 1.08-.84.89-.7-.14-1.13c-.03-.31-.05-.54-.05-.74s.02-.43.05-.73l.14-1.13-.89-.7-1.08-.84.7-1.21 1.27.51 1.04.42.9-.68c.43-.32.84-.56 1.25-.73l1.06-.43.16-1.13.2-1.35h1.39l.19 1.35.16 1.13 1.06.43c.43.18.83.41 1.23.71l.91.7 1.06-.43 1.27-.51.7 1.21-1.07.85-.89.7.14 1.13zM12 8c-2.21 0-4 1.79-4 4s1.79 4 4 4 4-1.79 4-4-1.79-4-4-4zm0 6c-1.1 0-2-.9-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .9 2 2-.9 2-2 2z"/></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="text">Settings</div>
      </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>




In general a clip-path: path will be your best option. Any CSS shape is likely to have unsatisfying and unresponsive issues.

Yeah, SVG is really the best option, but I'm beginner level with it, the reason I asked for CSS solution. I achieved something decent with clip-path, but there were some hardcoded numbers in order for the curve to match the circle.

I would create an SVG shape to serve as the background of the .indicator::before pseudo-element. I would start with a circle bisected by a line, then draw some paths in the corners, then join it all together into a single filled path.

You then need to encode the SVG for use in CSS. After setting it as the content of the .indicator::before pseudo-element, and deleting the .corners element which is no longer needed, the final result looks like this:

Snippet below to demonstrate.


const indicator = document.querySelector("[data-indicator]")

document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  let anchor
  if (e.target.matches("a")) {
    anchor = e.target
  } else {
    anchor = e.target.closest("a")
  }
  if (anchor != null) {
    const allAnchors = [...document.querySelectorAll("a")]
    const index = allAnchors.indexOf(anchor)
    indicator.style.setProperty("--position", index)
    document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(elem => {
      elem.classList.remove("active")
    })
    anchor.classList.add("active")
  }
})
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

:root {
  --icon-size: 2rem;
  --indicator-spacing: calc(var(--icon-size) / 8);
  --border-radius: calc(var(--icon-size) / 4);
  --nav-item-padding: calc(var(--icon-size) / 2);
  --background-color: #333;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  color: white;
}

.navbar-container {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  padding: 0 calc(var(--nav-item-padding) * 1.5);
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.list a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: var(--nav-item-padding);
}

.list .text {
  font-size: .8em;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 250ms ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(.5 * var(--nav-item-padding));
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

.list .icon {
  position: relative;
  transition: 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.list .icon svg {
  fill: currentColor;
  width: var(--icon-size);
  height: var(--icon-size);
  display: block;
}

.list .active .text {
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.list .active .icon {
  transform: translateY(calc(-50% - var(--nav-item-padding)));
}

.list {
  position: relative;
}

.indicator {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(var(--position) * (var(--icon-size) + var(--nav-item-padding) * 2));
  transition: 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.indicator::after, .indicator::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

.indicator::after {
  background-color: hsl(100, 100%, 50%);
  width: calc(var(--icon-size) * 2);
  height: calc(var(--icon-size) * 2);
  top: calc(-1 * var(--icon-size));
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.indicator::before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'%3F%3E%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 261.3 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M 261.29 50.002 C 254.134 50.002 247.631 54.09 245.969 60.432 C 241.212 83.005 221.119 100.003 197.056 100.003 C 181.263 100.003 167.18 92.681 158.021 81.26 C 155.639 78.412 149.785 72.471 145.755 69.829 C 123.211 55.046 95.066 52.813 68.823 51.867 C 44.982 51.007 23.961 50.016 0 50.002 C 23.961 49.987 44.982 48.996 68.823 48.136 C 95.066 47.19 123.211 44.957 145.755 30.174 C 149.785 27.532 155.639 21.591 158.021 18.743 C 167.18 7.322 181.263 0 197.056 0 C 221.119 0 241.212 16.998 245.969 39.571 C 247.631 45.913 254.134 50.002 261.29 50.002 Z' style='stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0px; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51);'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  height: calc((var(--icon-size) + var(--indicator-spacing)) * 2);
  aspect-ratio: 2613 / 1000;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--icon-size) - var(--indicator-spacing));
  left: calc(-1 * var(--indicator-spacing) - 105px);
}
<nav class="navbar-container">
  <ul class="list">
    <div style="--position: 0;" data-indicator class="indicator">
    </div>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">
      <div class="icon">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" ><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M12 5.69l5 4.5V18h-2v-6H9v6H7v-7.81l5-4.5M12 3L2 12h3v8h6v-6h2v6h6v-8h3L12 3z"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Home</div>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
      <div class="icon">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M12 5.9c1.16 0 2.1.94 2.1 2.1s-.94 2.1-2.1 2.1S9.9 9.16 9.9 8s.94-2.1 2.1-2.1m0 9c2.97 0 6.1 1.46 6.1 2.1v1.1H5.9V17c0-.64 3.13-2.1 6.1-2.1M12 4C9.79 4 8 5.79 8 8s1.79 4 4 4 4-1.79 4-4-1.79-4-4-4zm0 9c-2.67 0-8 1.34-8 4v3h16v-3c0-2.66-5.33-4-8-4z"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Account</div>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
      <div class="icon">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M20 2H4c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v18l4-4h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 14H6l-2 2V4h16v12z"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Messages</div>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
      <div class="icon">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M14.12 4l1.83 2H20v12H4V6h4.05l1.83-2h4.24M15 2H9L7.17 4H4c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h16c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V6c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2h-3.17L15 2zm-3 7c1.65 0 3 1.35 3 3s-1.35 3-3 3-3-1.35-3-3 1.35-3 3-3m0-2c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 5s2.24 5 5 5 5-2.24 5-5-2.24-5-5-5z"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Photos</div>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
      <div class="icon">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M19.43 12.98c.04-.32.07-.64.07-.98 0-.34-.03-.66-.07-.98l2.11-1.65c.19-.15.24-.42.12-.64l-2-3.46c-.09-.16-.26-.25-.44-.25-.06 0-.12.01-.17.03l-2.49 1c-.52-.4-1.08-.73-1.69-.98l-.38-2.65C14.46 2.18 14.25 2 14 2h-4c-.25 0-.46.18-.49.42l-.38 2.65c-.61.25-1.17.59-1.69.98l-2.49-1c-.06-.02-.12-.03-.18-.03-.17 0-.34.09-.43.25l-2 3.46c-.13.22-.07.49.12.64l2.11 1.65c-.04.32-.07.65-.07.98 0 .33.03.66.07.98l-2.11 1.65c-.19.15-.24.42-.12.64l2 3.46c.09.16.26.25.44.25.06 0 .12-.01.17-.03l2.49-1c.52.4 1.08.73 1.69.98l.38 2.65c.03.24.24.42.49.42h4c.25 0 .46-.18.49-.42l.38-2.65c.61-.25 1.17-.59 1.69-.98l2.49 1c.06.02.12.03.18.03.17 0 .34-.09.43-.25l2-3.46c.12-.22.07-.49-.12-.64l-2.11-1.65zm-1.98-1.71c.04.31.05.52.05.73 0 .21-.02.43-.05.73l-.14 1.13.89.7 1.08.84-.7 1.21-1.27-.51-1.04-.42-.9.68c-.43.32-.84.56-1.25.73l-1.06.43-.16 1.13-.2 1.35h-1.4l-.19-1.35-.16-1.13-1.06-.43c-.43-.18-.83-.41-1.23-.71l-.91-.7-1.06.43-1.27.51-.7-1.21 1.08-.84.89-.7-.14-1.13c-.03-.31-.05-.54-.05-.74s.02-.43.05-.73l.14-1.13-.89-.7-1.08-.84.7-1.21 1.27.51 1.04.42.9-.68c.43-.32.84-.56 1.25-.73l1.06-.43.16-1.13.2-1.35h1.39l.19 1.35.16 1.13 1.06.43c.43.18.83.41 1.23.71l.91.7 1.06-.43 1.27-.51.7 1.21-1.07.85-.89.7.14 1.13zM12 8c-2.21 0-4 1.79-4 4s1.79 4 4 4 4-1.79 4-4-1.79-4-4-4zm0 6c-1.1 0-2-.9-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .9 2 2-.9 2-2 2z"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Settings</div>
    </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>



It’s probably possible take the path out of this SVG and use it as a clip-path instead, but the end result would be the same.

Thanks, that's a great solution despite not CSS-only. I only wish we didn't have to add that -105px to .indicator::before's left. :) This needs to be done but with another hardcoded value for the right corner as well.

I'm also posting my own solution using clip-path as suggested by @Paulie_D since it has its own benefits and drawbacks compared to @Brett Donald's solution.
Here the drawback is I need to hardcode the point where the clipped content (watch for classes .clip-wrapper and .clip) hits the circle (::before of .indicator). I had to also put some left to .clip-wrapper but that's tightly coupled with the point of intersection so I count it as one situation of hardcoding.
I manually composed the curve using cubic bezier curve and respectively the mirrored one on the right, but that was relatively easy to do.
The wrapper is necessary so I had the two colors when clipping - white for the clipped content and dark for the rest.


const indicator = document.querySelector('[data-indicator]');

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let anchor;

    if (e.target.matches("a")) {
        anchor = e.target;
    } else {
        anchor = e.target.closest("a");
    }

    if (anchor != null) {
        const allAnchors = [...document.querySelectorAll("a")];
        const index = allAnchors.indexOf(anchor);
        indicator.style.setProperty("--position", index);

        document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(elem => {
            elem.classList.remove("active");
        });
        anchor.classList.add("active");
    }
});
*,
*::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

:root {
  --icon-size: 2rem;
  --nav-item-padding: calc(var(--icon-size) / 2);
  --background-color: #333;
  --border-radius: calc(var(--icon-size) / 4);
  --indicator-spacing: calc(var(--icon-size) / 8);
}

body {
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  color: white;
}

.navbar-container {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10rem;
  padding: 0 calc(var(--nav-item-padding) * 4); // * 1.5
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.list a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: var(--nav-item-padding);
}

.list .text {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 500ms ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(0.5 * var(--nav-item-padding));
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

.list .icon svg {
  fill: currentColor;
  width: var(--icon-size);
  height: var(--icon-size);
  display: block;
}

.list .active .text {
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.list .icon {
  position: relative;
  transition: 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.list .active .icon {
  transform: translateY(calc(-50% - var(--nav-item-padding)));
}

/* .list .active::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: var(--border-radius);
  height: var(--border-radius);
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--indicator-spacing));
  left: calc(.2 * var(--indicator-spacing));
  transform: translateX(-100%); 
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  border-width: calc(var(--indicator-spacing));
  border-color: var(--background-color);
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
}

.list .active::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: var(--border-radius);
  height: var(--border-radius);
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--indicator-spacing));
  right: calc(.2 * var(--indicator-spacing));
  transform: translateX(100%); 
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-width: calc(var(--indicator-spacing));
  border-color: var(--background-color);
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
} */

.indicator {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(
    var(--position) * (var(--icon-size) + var(--nav-item-padding) * 2)
  );
  transition: 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.indicator::before,
.indicator::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.indicator::after {
  background-color: hsl(100, 100%, 50%);
  width: calc(var(--icon-size) * 2);
  height: calc(var(--icon-size) * 2);
  top: calc(-1 * var(--icon-size));
  // left: 1px; // comment for other solutions
  /* left: calc(-.5 * var(--icon-size)); */
}

.indicator::before {
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  width: calc((var(--icon-size) + var(--indicator-spacing)) * 2);
  height: calc((var(--icon-size) + var(--indicator-spacing)) * 2);
  top: calc(-1 * var(--icon-size) - var(--indicator-spacing));
  left: calc(-1 * var(--indicator-spacing));
}

.list {
  position: relative;
}

// .corners::before {
//   content: "";
//   position: absolute;
//   box-sizing: content-box;
//   width: var(--border-radius);
//   height: var(--border-radius);
//   background-color: white;
//   z-index: 1;
//   top: calc(-1 * var(--indicator-spacing));
//   left: calc(.2 * var(--indicator-spacing));
//   transform: translateX(-100%);
//   border-top-right-radius: 100%;
//   border-width: calc(var(--indicator-spacing));
//   border-color: var(--background-color);
//   border-style: solid;
//   border-bottom: none;
//   border-left: none;
// }

// .corners::after {
//   content: "";
//   position: absolute;
//   box-sizing: content-box;
//   width: var(--border-radius);
//   height: var(--border-radius);
//   background-color: white;
//   z-index: 1;
//   top: calc(-1 * var(--indicator-spacing));
//   left: calc(var(--icon-size) * 2 - .2 * var(--indicator-spacing));
//   border-top-left-radius: 100%;
//   border-width: calc(var(--indicator-spacing));
//   border-color: var(--background-color);
//   border-style: solid;
//   border-bottom: none;
//   border-right: none;
// }

// .corners::before {
//   position: absolute;
//   content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'%3F%3E%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 261.3 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M 261.29 50.002 C 254.134 50.002 247.631 54.09 245.969 60.432 C 241.212 83.005 221.119 100.003 197.056 100.003 C 181.263 100.003 167.18 92.681 158.021 81.26 C 155.639 78.412 149.785 72.471 145.755 69.829 C 123.211 55.046 95.066 52.813 68.823 51.867 C 44.982 51.007 23.961 50.016 0 50.002 C 23.961 49.987 44.982 48.996 68.823 48.136 C 95.066 47.19 123.211 44.957 145.755 30.174 C 149.785 27.532 155.639 21.591 158.021 18.743 C 167.18 7.322 181.263 0 197.056 0 C 221.119 0 241.212 16.998 245.969 39.571 C 247.631 45.913 254.134 50.002 261.29 50.002 Z' style='stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0px; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51);'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
//   height: calc((var(--icon-size) + var(--indicator-spacing)) * 2);
//   aspect-ratio: 2613 / 1000;
//   top: calc(-1 * var(--icon-size) - var(--indicator-spacing));
//   left: calc(-1 * var(--indicator-spacing) - 105px);
// }

// .corners::after {
//   position: absolute;
//   content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'%3F%3E%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 261.3 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cdefs/%3E%3Cpath d='M 261.29 50.002 C 254.134 50.002 247.631 54.09 245.969 60.432 C 241.212 83.005 221.119 100.003 197.056 100.003 C 181.263 100.003 167.18 92.681 158.021 81.26 C 155.639 78.412 149.785 72.471 145.755 69.829 C 123.211 55.046 95.066 52.813 68.823 51.867 C 44.982 51.007 23.961 50.016 0 50.002 C 23.961 49.987 44.982 48.996 68.823 48.136 C 95.066 47.19 123.211 44.957 145.755 30.174 C 149.785 27.532 155.639 21.591 158.021 18.743 C 167.18 7.322 181.263 0 197.056 0 C 221.119 0 241.212 16.998 245.969 39.571 C 247.631 45.913 254.134 50.002 261.29 50.002 Z' style='stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0px; fill: rgb(51, 51, 51); transform-box: fill-box; transform-origin: 50%25 50%25;' transform='matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, -0.000009, -0.000001)'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
//   height: calc((var(--icon-size) + var(--indicator-spacing)) * 2);
//   aspect-ratio: 2613 / 1000;
//   top: calc(-1 * var(--icon-size) - var(--indicator-spacing));
//   left: calc(-1 * var(--indicator-spacing) - 10px);
// }

.clip-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
}

.clip {
  transform: skewY(
    0.001deg
  ); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542919/clip-path-on-chrome-leaves-a-strange-line-on-the-edge
  z-index: 1;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: white;
}

.clip-wrapper.left {
  left: 8px;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.clip-wrapper.left .clip {
  background: white;
  clip-path: path("M 0 0 C 25 0, 35 0, 64 26.9 L 64 64 L 0 64 L 0 0z");
}

.clip-wrapper.right {
  left: -8px;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.clip-wrapper.right .clip {
  clip-path: path("M 64 0 C 39 0, 29 0, 0 26.9 L 0 64 L 64 64 L 64 0z");
}
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar-container">
      <ul class="list">
        <div style="--position: 0;" data-indicator class="indicator">
          <div class="clip-wrapper left">
            <div class="clip">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clip-wrapper right">
            <div class="clip">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- <div class="corners"></div> -->
        </div>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="active">
            <div class="icon">
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                fill="#000000"
              >
                <path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" />
                <path
                  d="M12 5.69l5 4.5V18h-2v-6H9v6H7v-7.81l5-4.5M12 3L2 12h3v8h6v-6h2v6h6v-8h3L12 3z"
                />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="text">Home</div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#000000"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M12 5.9c1.16 0 2.1.94 2.1 2.1s-.94 2.1-2.1 2.1S9.9 9.16 9.9 8s.94-2.1 2.1-2.1m0 9c2.97 0 6.1 1.46 6.1 2.1v1.1H5.9V17c0-.64 3.13-2.1 6.1-2.1M12 4C9.79 4 8 5.79 8 8s1.79 4 4 4 4-1.79 4-4-1.79-4-4-4zm0 9c-2.67 0-8 1.34-8 4v3h16v-3c0-2.66-5.33-4-8-4z"/></svg>
            </div>
            <div class="text">Account</div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#000000"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M20 2H4c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v18l4-4h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 14H6l-2 2V4h16v12z"/></svg>
            </div>
            <div class="text">Message</div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#000000"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M14.12 4l1.83 2H20v12H4V6h4.05l1.83-2h4.24M15 2H9L7.17 4H4c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h16c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V6c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2h-3.17L15 2zm-3 7c1.65 0 3 1.35 3 3s-1.35 3-3 3-3-1.35-3-3 1.35-3 3-3m0-2c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 5s2.24 5 5 5 5-2.24 5-5-2.24-5-5-5z"/></svg>
            </div>
            <div class="text">Photos</div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <div class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#000000"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none"/><path d="M19.43 12.98c.04-.32.07-.64.07-.98 0-.34-.03-.66-.07-.98l2.11-1.65c.19-.15.24-.42.12-.64l-2-3.46c-.09-.16-.26-.25-.44-.25-.06 0-.12.01-.17.03l-2.49 1c-.52-.4-1.08-.73-1.69-.98l-.38-2.65C14.46 2.18 14.25 2 14 2h-4c-.25 0-.46.18-.49.42l-.38 2.65c-.61.25-1.17.59-1.69.98l-2.49-1c-.06-.02-.12-.03-.18-.03-.17 0-.34.09-.43.25l-2 3.46c-.13.22-.07.49.12.64l2.11 1.65c-.04.32-.07.65-.07.98 0 .33.03.66.07.98l-2.11 1.65c-.19.15-.24.42-.12.64l2 3.46c.09.16.26.25.44.25.06 0 .12-.01.17-.03l2.49-1c.52.4 1.08.73 1.69.98l.38 2.65c.03.24.24.42.49.42h4c.25 0 .46-.18.49-.42l.38-2.65c.61-.25 1.17-.59 1.69-.98l2.49 1c.06.02.12.03.18.03.17 0 .34-.09.43-.25l2-3.46c.12-.22.07-.49-.12-.64l-2.11-1.65zm-1.98-1.71c.04.31.05.52.05.73 0 .21-.02.43-.05.73l-.14 1.13.89.7 1.08.84-.7 1.21-1.27-.51-1.04-.42-.9.68c-.43.32-.84.56-1.25.73l-1.06.43-.16 1.13-.2 1.35h-1.4l-.19-1.35-.16-1.13-1.06-.43c-.43-.18-.83-.41-1.23-.71l-.91-.7-1.06.43-1.27.51-.7-1.21 1.08-.84.89-.7-.14-1.13c-.03-.31-.05-.54-.05-.74s.02-.43.05-.73l.14-1.13-.89-.7-1.08-.84.7-1.21 1.27.51 1.04.42.9-.68c.43-.32.84-.56 1.25-.73l1.06-.43.16-1.13.2-1.35h1.39l.19 1.35.16 1.13 1.06.43c.43.18.83.41 1.23.71l.91.7 1.06-.43 1.27-.51.7 1.21-1.07.85-.89.7.14 1.13zM12 8c-2.21 0-4 1.79-4 4s1.79 4 4 4 4-1.79 4-4-1.79-4-4-4zm0 6c-1.1 0-2-.9-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .9 2 2-.9 2-2 2z"/></svg>
            </div>
            <div class="text">Settings</div>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>



