# clip-path horizontal white line in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, clip-path

Got clip-path set on div with background image. When in Chrome horizontal white lines appear through the div / background image. Anyone know how to remove this?

See screenshot:
[Screenshot with horizontal white line bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSmSu.jpg)

Here is also a link to the course page
https://www.sunderland.ac.uk/study/health-paramedic-clinical-sciences/undergraduate-biomedical-science/#facilities

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clip-path on Chrome leaves a strange line on the edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542919/clip-path-on-chrome-leaves-a-strange-line-on-the-edge)

Answer (score 4):

Ran into this same issue recently. I added a `-1px` margin **to the edge with the white line**.

```
.clipped-box {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 60px) 0%, 100% 60px, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

I had this issue when trying to stack two sections with clipping masks. The top section had the white line on the bottom. So I pulled the next section up into it.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been spotted before, see [Clip-path on Chrome leaves a strange line on the edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542919/clip-path-on-chrome-leaves-a-strange-line-on-the-edge) and [CSS - Strange border appearing on Chrome mobile with clip-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840094/css-strange-border-appearing-on-chrome-mobile-with-clip-path)

It appears to be a Chrome rendering bug.

For your case, I was able to make the line disappear by setting a height to your polygon container:

```
.course_page #facilities .facility--menu {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0,100% 5%,100% 95%,0 100%);
    height: 25em;
}
```

The height is only slightly higher than current.

No other CSS properties I've tested seem to have an effect on the line.

Comment: This would be a great fix using the height however text under the different tabs has different lengths so the div cuts off the text.